# Italic in some words of the title

Tags: fonts, sectioning, formatting, italic

I want to use a title with a foreign word, which should be in italic. I use KOMA-script.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

The text.

\section{Foo \textit{bar}}
\section{Foo \itshape bar}
\section{Foo \normalfont \bfseries \itshape bar}
\subsection{Foo \textit{bar}}
\subsection{Foo \itshape bar}
\subsection{Foo \normalfont \bfseries \itshape bar}

\end{document}
```

`\textit` does not work, neither does `\itshape` (why?)

`\normalfont\itshape` almost work, but it removes the bold in the title.

`\normalfont\bfseries\itshape` works, but not in the table of contents where it adds bold...

So, how can I do it?

*Edit:* As Marco Daniel pointed out, the problem was that the font I used (Biolinum) did not have a bold italic shape. Telling fontspec to use a different font for the bolditalic solved the issue.

Comment: you should always isolate font changes in headings, like `{\itshape bar}`, otherwise there can be repercussions in derivative uses, like tables of contents.  see the example in the answer by @MarcoDaniel.

Comment: For the future, please add the necessary information: if you compile your example as is, it shows bold italic in the titles, so the problem depends on something else you do in your document.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your log file you will find warnings like

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

This means you don't use a font which has such a combination. See: Warning: [“Font shape … not available”](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fontunavail)

Load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and you will get:

[image]